# Java debugger not suspended/stopped for the line breakpoints

Tags: java, debugging

I created a simple application for summing 3 integer no's. I added 3 breakpoints in all the 3 different lines but none of the line breakpoints hitting while debugging this code.

```
public class StepDebugging {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int i,j,k;
    i= j = k = 1;
    i =
            i //line breakpoint1 here (line 8)
            +
            j //line breakpoint2 here (line 10)
            +
            k;//line breakpoint3 here (line 12)
    System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

I checked the line no table for this code and wonder to see that all the lines are missing where the breakpoints are added.

```
public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
LineNumberTable:
  line 6: 0
  line 7: 6
  line 13: 12
  line 14: 19
LocalVariableTable:
  Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
      0      20     0  args   [Ljava/lang/String;
      6      14     1     i   I
      5      15     2     j   I
      3      17     3     k   I
```

I google this issue, but not found any relevant article or post. I debugged this app in Intellij and Eclipse, both has the same behavior.

Answer (score 1):

As said in `Jetbrains` docs, IntelliJ IDEA supports 4 kinds of breakpoints:

- Line breakpoints
- Method breakpoints
- Field watchpoints
- Exception breakpoints

All of `i = i + j + k;` is one single line and you want to set breakpoints in the middle of a line which is not listed in `Jetbrains` docs.

more info: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-breakpoints.html

if you want to check `i`, `j` or `k` value before `sum` operation, just put a breakpoint in `i = ...` line and check those values in `variables` window.

besides, in debug mode, if you pass that line in Intellij IDEA, you can see the final values in front of any line.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However i believe your answer is  partially correct in terms of "breakpoints in the middle" because if i modified the code (line no 10) by replacing +j to any method say foo() that return int value, then the breakpoint hits line no 10.